# Error: "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported" when using crypto module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm developing a Node.js application and encountering an error related to the **crypto module** when using cryptographic hash functions. Here's the error message I'm seeing:

```
error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:466:5
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12
    at C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\StudyNotion\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
```

The error seems to be related to the creation of a hash using the createHash function from the crypto module. I've tried updating Node.js, clearing the cache, and reinstalling dependencies, but the error persists.

Can anyone help me understand the cause of this error and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!